# Are there some flex libraries for dashboard, chart, graph?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flex4

We want to use flex tech to replace our old dashboard ui.
Could you share some flex libs to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check out Tour de Flex. They have some charting components in there as well. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what you are trying to do. Check this for charting:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part1_charting_1.html

Likely it's best to use components like the one above and build your own dashboard.

Comment: I also suggest the "built in" Flex charting components ... they're really cool. Check this out too http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/drillDown/app.html